# ERROR in Can't bind to 'readOnly' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

Tags: html, angular, typescript

guys i'm trying to install and configure a project of mine in angular. But i face these errors after doing NPM  install.
here is the output after doing a installation.

```
ERROR in Can't bind to 'readOnly' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. ("lex="5" >
                        <button mat-icon-button mat-sm-button [disabled]="searchValempty" [ERROR ->][readonly]="!searchValempty" color="primary" class="my-search" matTooltip="Search" (click)="
searchFil")
Can't bind to 'readOnly' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. ("ex="5" >
                        <button mat-icon-button mat-sm-button [disabled]="!searchValempty" [ERROR ->][readonly]="!searchValempty" color="primary" class="my-search" matTooltip="Search" (click)=
"searchFil")
Can't bind to 'readOnly' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. ("ex="5" >
                        <button mat-icon-button mat-sm-button [disabled]="!searchValempty" [ERROR ->][readonly]="!searchValempty" color="primary" class="my-search" matTooltip="Search" (click)=
"searchFil")
Can't bind to 'readOnly' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. ("
                                <button mat-icon-button mat-sm-button [disabled]="!searchValempty" [ERROR ->][readonly]="!searchValempty" color="primary" class="my-search" matTooltip="Search"
(click)="searchFil")
Can't bind to 'readOnly' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. (""5" >
                        <button mat-icon-button mat-sm-button [disabled]="!searchVlnValempty" [ERROR ->][readonly]="!searchVlnValempty" color="primary" class="my-search" matTooltip="Search" (c
lick)="search")
Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'li'. ("           [class.disable]='!vlnmeta.meta.nextPage'
                                                [ERROR ->][disabled]='!vlnmeta.meta.nextPage'>
                                                <span><a href="j")
Can't bind to 'fullscreenControl' since it isn't a known property of 'agm-polyline'.
1. If 'agm-polyline' is an Angular component and it has 'fullscreenControl' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'agm-polyline' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("        </button>
                <agm-polyline strokeColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)" *ngIf="!ltrackchk" [ERROR ->][fullscreenControl]="true">
                    <agm-polyline-point *ngFor="let loc of traceroutelist")
```

Comment: The errors say you that `readonly` is all in **lower case** and you can not disabled a `li`

Comment: ok thankyou @Eliseo  how can i rectify the agm-map error's ? it is not working when i write "[readonly]=" to "[readOnly]="

Comment: well, agm-map is a component (and I'm don't know if has a property (a `@Input` readOnly, or readOnly). (the others are html tags and sure is readonly